# Why the layer can be loaded to Google Maps not OpenStreetMap using MapServer?

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers-2, mapserver

I am using OpenLayers WMS to load a layer from the PostGIS Raster Table, the JavaScript on OpenLayers are as following:

```
function init(){
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    var imagery = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "Global Imagery",
        "http://maps.opengeo.org/geowebcache/service/wms",
        {
            layers: "bluemarble",
        }
     );
    map.addLayer(imagery);
    localWMS = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( 
        "Local WMS layers",
        "http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?MAP=C:/Users/gyu1/Desktop/Newfolder/mapserver.map",
        {
            layers: 'polygon',
            transparent: true
        }, {
            isBaseLayer: false
        }
    );

    map.addLayer(localWMS);
    map.setCenter(
        new OpenLayers.LonLat(1.147, 52.472).transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            map.getProjectionObject()
        ), 5
    );
    map.addControl( new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
}
```

The map file linking the Data and styling are as following:

```
MAP
    NAME "polygon"
    WEB 
        METADATA
            "wms_title" "MapServer"
            "wms_onlineresource" "http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?MAP=C:/Users/gyu1/Desktop/Newfolder/mapserver.map"
            "wms_srs" "EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857"
        END
    END
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:3857"
    END
    LAYER
        NAME "postgis"
        TYPE raster
        STATUS ON
        DATA "PG:host=localhost port=5432 dbname='fusiongeo' user='postgres' password='**' schema='public' table='london' mode='2'" 
        PROCESSING "NODATA=-9999"
        PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"
        CLASS
            NAME "boring"
            EXPRESSION ([pixel] < 50)
            COLOR 250 100 0
        END
        CLASS
            NAME "mildly interesting"
            EXPRESSION ([pixel] > 50 AND [pixel] < 100)
            COLOR 100 0 0
        END
        CLASS
            NAME "very interesting"
            EXPRESSION ([pixel] >= 100)
            COLOR 0 50 0
        END
    END     
END # end map
```

It works for the Google Base Map not the OpenStreetMap. I am quite new with the MapServer, OpenLayers and I don't know how to change the SRS to make it work.

The data in PostGIS are in EPSG:3857.

Comment: EPSG:3857 is web mercator, the same than EPSG:900913 which unit is meter. EPSG:4326 is WGS84 in lat/lon degree. Maybe the right projection unit, resolution and extent are not well define in OpenLayers

Comment: You need to set the projection of the map. I don't see that in your code.

Comment: You can just append epsg:900913 to the wms_srs line so Mapserver will advertise in WMS that it can reproject to that srs as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
 map.setCenter(
            new OpenLayers.LonLat(1.147, 52.472).transform(
                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                map.getProjectionObject()
            ), 5
        );
```

you're mixing things like above. If Mapserver is serving your Postgis data set in EPSG:3857, you don't need EPSG:4326 in your mapfile. The EPSG:4326, however, will be needed in your html if you need to convert utm values to geographical ones (ie. to decimal degrees). It also will be needed if you want to add some WMS in 4326 (so in the mapfile and openlayers code). OSM is in Spherical Mercator and EPSG:3857 in your mapfile is correct. Check here for some working examples:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/aguiguy/ZAZN8/
http://jsfiddle.net/UAxun/155/
http://jsfiddle.net/VictorVelarde/DbCgt/
```

About your mapfile, what I meant was for instance:

```
DATA "geom FROM table USING UNIQUE id USING SRID=4326"
```

which works for a table in EPSG:4326, and this goes into your mapfile. Your mapfile has this:

```
DATA "PG:host=localhost port=5432 dbname='fusiongeo' user='postgres' password='**' schema='public' table='london' mode='2'"
```

and I think it should be something like this (you has missed so far the connection option):

```
CONNECTION "PG:host=localhost port=5432 dbname='fusiongeo' user='postgres' password='**'"
DATA "geom FROM YOURtable USING UNIQUE id USING SRID=3857"
```

Check here for some more basic info: http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/wiki/PostGIS

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi, Gery. I updates my javascript but it still shows the same error. My new javascript is as following:

Comment: I think something wrong with the Map file wms_srs: code

Comment: Hi Yu, you need only ´"wms_srs" "EPSG:3857"´ in your mapfile. Also you need more info about the file type (PNG, etc) and tags like SIZE, EXTENT, UNITS, etc, check here for good map file examples: http://live.osgeo.org/es/quickstart/mapserver_quickstart.html, http://atlantic.evsc.virginia.edu/~jhp7e/advgis/local/2005/Sample_Mapserver.pdf?meid=38

Comment: Hi Gery, is not the case. I already tried with that before, it just doesn't work with OpenStreet Map. It works with Google map even without SIZE, EXTENT,Units. Since it connects to the PostGIS raster table, I don't think the user need to specify the details. The MapServer can read it from table.

Comment: I see, and you also specified the SRID in your postgis call in mapserver?

Comment: I specified the SRID 3857 when I loaded the raster (ASC-II) to the postgis. Does it what you mean? Still wait for the solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Yu, I edited my answer, please take a look at it.

Comment: Hi Gery, sorry, it doesn't even load the data to Google Map. I just follow this example of Map File :[link](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_FAQ.html#id546503)

Comment: well that's a question for the Postgis mailing list, probably you can get more support there because I think that should work, try here: http://postgis.net/support/

Comment: Thanks. I will keep you updates about the problem and solution

Comment: Hi Gery, The problem solved finally. I just replace the  "wms_srs"  "EPSG:3857" to "wms_srs"  "EPSG:900913" and it works. It seems 900913 and 3857 are identical, but I don't know why 900913 works. Thanks

Comment: Hi Yu, nice to hear that you solved that, that's one more reason why I always use 900913 instead of 3857.

Answer (score 1):

Updates JavaScript

```
 var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
                displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                units: "m"
        });
  var imagery = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "Simple OSM Map");
  map.addLayer(imagery);

        localWMS = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Local WMS layers",
                  "http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?MAP=C:/Users/gyu1/Desktop/Newfolder/mapserver.map",
                  {layers: 'polygon',transparent: true},
                  {isBaseLayer: false} );
        map.addLayer(localWMS);

        var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon,lat).transform(map.displayProjection, map.projection);
        map.setCenter(lonlat, 5);

        map.addControl( new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
    }
```

The problem was solved by replacing `"wms_srs" "EPSG:3857"` with `"wms_srs" "EPSG:900913"` in the map file.